# css3 transitions not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, css

I am trying to get a transition working on some bullets in firefox, but I am having no luck. It works on chrome, safari, opera and ie. Here is my css. I just want the background-image adjusted to my y positioning.

```
#slideshow-nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 3px;
    background: url('images/bullets.png');
    background-position-y: 17px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#slideshow-nav a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 3px;
    background: url('images/bullets.png');
    background-position-y: 0px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#slideshow-nav li.activeSlide a { 
    display: block;
    background: url('images/bullets.png');
    background-position-y: 0px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: A jsfiddle demo would be helpful.

Comment: Also, CSS3 transitions don't work for _all_ CSS properties, so be careful about that.

Comment: Does it work if you change your timing function?  Unable to tell from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/timing-function#Browser_compatibility, but perhaps ease-in-out is not supported by firefox?

Comment: It doesn't have to do with your problem, but you don't need to declare the transition on the :hover state, nor in the activeSlide. Transitions are declared on the "normal" state of an element and fire whenever that state changes, so no need to redeclare them. No need to redeclare the display, with, height, etc either.

Comment: I didn't know that Cmorales. Thats good to know :) Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge (which most certainly is incomplete) `background-position-y` is not a valid property. My guess is Firefox is not recognizing it. Try:

```
background-position: 0 17px;
```

going to

```
background-position: 0 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.menuhvr { background-image:url('images/bullets.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:left; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 20px; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight:lighter; text-transform: none; border: 0px; display: block; -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s; -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s; -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s; transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s; height: 25px; line-height: 25px; }

a.menuhvr:hover { background-image: url(images/bullet1.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color: #104595; background-position: right; margin: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 25px; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight:lighter; background-color: #104595; border: 0px; display: block; height: 25px; line-height: 25px; }
```

If you wish you can change both different bullet images or can use single